# Is any nonsingular operator on a vector space that preserves linear independence necessarily linear?

Tags: vector-spaces

This is related to this question [Change of basis with a nonlinear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096325/change-of-basis-with-a-nonlinear-operator/1919264#1919264).

Is it true that any nonsingular operator that preserves the linear independence of any set must be linear?

In other words, does there exist a nonlinear nonsingular operator that preserves the linear independence of any set?

Comment: What does "nonsingular" mean for a nonlinear operator?  In one dimension, is the map $f(x) = x^3$ a counterexample?

Comment: I was  going to write bijective instead of nonsingular, but I wrote nonsingular because that's what a comment in the related question mentioned.
Yes $f(x)=x^3$ is the example I mentioned in the related question. I suppose I mean it in general, that is, in any dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a field that has a nontrivial automorphism, you can choose a basis and apply the automorphism to the coordinates in that basis. This is nonlinear, invertible, and preserves linear independence. An example would be $\mathbb C$ with complex conjugation.

Comment: In this case, what is your take on such operators being considered *not terribly useful* in the comment in the related question?

Comment: @weakmoons it's hard to say when and if something will be useful. The answer to that question is not wrong by saying it isn't useful in that specific context. The important thing in your question is that there is a linear transformation taking any basis to any other. This example shows a function does not need to be linear to always take bases to bases.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$

$$f(a,b) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}(a,b)$$

is clearly not linear.