Looking for an intuitive explanation of transition matrices for change of basis
So, I have my final in Linear Algebra next week, and I have maintained an A throughout the term. However, I feel I still do not have a strong conceptual grasp of the concept of how the transition matrix relates to a change in coordinate representation for some basis.
I can use the formulas presented in the text to come to a correct answer most of the time by simply following the rules presented; however, I am having issues attaching an intuitive understanding as to how I have come to the correct answer or why it is the case (preferably geometrically if it can be shown).
As an aside, I have studied discrete mathematics, and I have related the vector space basis to the basis of a recursive function; however, I do not know if this understanding is correct. Clarification on this point would also be appreciated. If anyone has a video or intuitive explanation of these topics, any help would be much appreciated!
EDIT: Specifically, I am looking for a geometric explanation or intuitive explanation of a problem such as
Let
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.$$
For $$T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ relative to the standard basis, find the matrix for $T$ relative to:
$$B' = \{(1,1,0),(1,-1,0),(0,0,1)\}.$$
Without showing my work, my answer is
$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.$$
Can someone provide an intuitive illustration as to what is being related here? Or provide a video which accomplishes the previously stated.
Edit 2: If I am not being clear, I understand that I can use the formula
$$A'= P^{-1}AP$$
to solve this problem, and I have no problem doing that. My question is: what is happening geometrically within the vector space when I perform this operation?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have edited the post to help clarify what I would like to be expounded upon.

Take a look here.

I have added another edit to try to help clarify my problem. I can solve the problem, but I want to establish a more intuitive understanding as to what I am actually doing. Not analytically if possible, preferably geometrically as I can perform the pertinent algebra.

The geometric interpretation in 2D or 3D is simple, we are referring all to the new base, usually is the algebraic part which is not so clearly understood.

Can you explain where the formula $A'= P^{-1}AP$ comes from and why it works? If so you don't have anything more to learn.

Why $P$ has vectors $B'$ as columns? This is the key point.

I used the $$A' = P^{-1}AP$$ to solve the equation, and can explain it algebraically. The geometric interpretation was never shown to me and though it may be simple that is what I am looking for.

You are misusing the term transition matrix. This appears in a completely different context. I am removing the tag.

Is P not a transition matrix from B' to B?

@ZacharyZastrow Translations in mathematics don't mean what they do in English. In mathematics, a translation is a transformation that takes a point $v$ in a space to a point $v+a$ where $a$ is a constant added to all of the vectors of the space. For example, $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+1,y+2,z+3)$ is a translation of all points in $\mathbb R^3$ by the constant $(1,2,3)$. These transformations are not linear so that is not what happens in a change of coordinates.

@JohnDouma That’s yet another inappropriate term. ;)

@ZacharyZastrow The geometric interpretation for $P$ comes from the answer to the question: Why $P$ has vectors of $B′$ as columns?

@ZacharyZastrow Can you answer to this question or not?

@user I can answer this question. I just want to see a geometric representation of what is happening so that I can visualize it more intuitively.

@ZacharyZastrow My answer would be as follows. We have that $Pe_1=b_1$ and so on, and therefore, by linearity, $P$ sends/transforms vectors from the standard basis to the new basis.

Consider in 2D the linear transformation  $T\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ swapping the canonical basis vectors, namely: $T(e_1)=e_2$ and $T(e_2)=e_1$. Therefore, $T$ maps a point of the canonically-oriented-plane to its "mirrored" point with respect to the bisector line of the 1st and 3rd quadrants. Now consider the change of basis $e_1\mapsto e'_1=-e_1$ and $e_2\mapsto e'_2=e_2$; this amounts to changing the orientation of the x-axis, so we expect that, in this basis, $T$ maps a point of the so-oriented-plane to its "mirrored" point with respect to the bisector line of the 2nd and 4th quadrants. And in fact, as per the rule that you know and mentioned in the Edit 2, the representative matrix of $T$ in the base $B:=(e_i)_{i=1,2}$:
$$T_{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
transforms, upon the change of basis $B\to B'$, into:
\begin{alignat}{1}
T_{B'} &= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{alignat}

Is every change of basis necessarily a linear transformation?

I ask this question because the before and after matrices in my first example are similar, so this made me think that it was not a linear transformation.

Not "necessarily", but thence you get "out of linear algebra". See e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096325/1092170
